# Maximum of a convolution

Tags: optimization, convolution

I have a function $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}_+$ which has a unique maximum at $x=0$. $f$ can be symmetric or asymmetric. I am interested on the mollified-f function

$$\tilde{f}(x)=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\varphi(y)f(x-y)dy,\,\,\, \epsilon>0$$

I wonder if there are general results on the [Mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) $\varphi$, such that $\tilde{f}$ also has a unique maximum (not necessarily at $0$).

Comment: In computer vision, there are a number of results showing that if one requires [non-creation of local extrema, along with a few other reasonable conditions,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-space_axioms) the Gaussian function is the unique choice of convolution kernel (up to scaling and translation). Those additional conditions probably don't apply in your case, but I thought it might still be useful to know, and the link above has lots of references.